# Windows Event Log SystemTime format

Tags: windows-7, windows, time, date-time, event-log

The follwing timestamp was created during an Windows Security Log

```
TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2013-10-07T07:31:09.122037600Z
```

In this timestamp I can't understand what `122037600Z` part means? Do they represent milliseconds or something? Please i need your help.

```
Placeholder
String  Meaning
YYYY    four-digit year
MM  two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
DD  two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
hh  two digits of hour (00 through 23)
mm  two digits of minute (00 through 59)
ss  two digits of second (00 through 59)
s   one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
TZD time zone designator (“Z” or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part after the integer second is the fractional second.  The `Z` takes the place of the time zone to indicate UTC.  It could also be written `2013-10-07T07:31:09.122037600+00:00`

```
122037600 fractional second
Z         Zulu, indicating UTC as time zone
```